# Using Sqlite3, create a slug version of a full title

Tags: sqlite, slug

I have a sqlite3 database table.  I added a column called title_slug.  I want to take the contents of title column, and update the new title_slug column with a slug version.  Can I do this straight from sqlite3 or do I have to code it outside of the program?

Comment: It depends. You'll need to post an example, showing a representative title and the slug you want to derive from it.

Comment: Well, let's say title would be "Top 10: This is a sample Title!" then I need it to be converted into the slug "top-10-this-is-a-sample-title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of, there are no loops in SQLite.
A not very generic solution could be:

```
UPDATE mytab SET title_slug = replace(replace(title_slug, ' ', '-'), '!', '')
```

but you would have to add many chars to replace ?!